# Drag Shadow Using Item Touch Helper android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

ItemTouchhelper Class in android helps only to move the entire view around the recyclerview. Is it possible to make a shadow of a view to be dragged(The original view to be in its place-fixed) using the Item touchHelper class?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I'm looking for the same. The tutorial from Paul Burke is very good, but it indeed only allows to drag within the Recyclerview.

Comment: @Jeroen I finally added both recyclerview and the fake object to be moved into a single container and on long press for an item in the recycelrview I showed this fake view with respect to the coordinates of the original view and that was two years back FYI

Comment: Oké, thanks for the response. This worked? You still got the nice effect of the ItemTouchHelper with replacing the items? Because when I try something like the the ItemTouchHelper loses it's ondrag.

Answer (score 4):

I overrode onChildDraw and made my own shadow

```
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        if (isCurrentlyActive) {
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
                // make shadown
                isRotated = true;
            }
        } else {
            // view is going back to orig
            if (isRotated) {
                // undo shadow
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way to achieve shadow on the dragged item (for API >= 21 since it relies on elevation).

Declare an attribute in `attrs.xml`:

```xml
<attr name="draggedItemElevation" format="dimension"/>
```

Set the attribute value in your theme:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="draggedItemElevation">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Use this callback for the `ItemTouchHelper`:

```kotlin
class DragItemTouchHelperCallback : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    // Get elevation in pixels from ?attr/draggedItemElevation.
    private val elevation = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            intArrayOf(R.attr.editDraggedItemElevation)).use {
        it.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0).toFloat()
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                             dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
        val view = viewHolder.itemView
        view.translationX = dX
        view.translationY = dY
        if (isCurrentlyActive) {
            ViewCompat.setElevation(view, elevation)
        }
    }

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        val view = viewHolder.itemView
        view.translationX = 0f
        view.translationY = 0f
        ViewCompat.setElevation(view, 0f)
    }

    override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                                  viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will temporarily change the dragged item elevation to `?attr/draggedItemElevation`, then set it back to 0 when the item is dropped.

Answer (score -2):

So, you just want a "preview" drag with a shadow...?

A `DragShadow` is easily achieved, when you call `startDrag`:

```
view.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0); //clipData can be null.
```

For an excellent tutorial on how to handle Drag & Drop, I recommend the one from [Paul Burke](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.ppxawgo10). He  defines a background, to show the user on which position the view will be placed.

If this does not answer your question, please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: I want the same effect as what happens with a drag shadow builder but I want it to be achieved using Item touch helper class. Still If u dont get me plz reply

Comment: this works with a touch helper, please refer to the tutorial,it is explained there. You need to tell the view to start a drag, I don't think there is any way around this. :)

Comment: @yennsarah I don't see anything about the dropshadow in that guide or his source code. In fact even when compiling his source there is no background property or dropshadow.

Comment: In Paul Burke's tutorial that you linked, he uses `ItemTouchHelper.startDrag()` which only accepts one parameter. It's different to `View.startDrag()`, which is deprecated, and may not work for RecyclerView rows.